# Powershell, is it possible to flush/clear output-stream

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to flush/clear Powershells output stream inside a function?

Use case: I'm calling PS functions from other developers in my psm1 file, and I want to use the output stream to return a numeric return value to the caller.
My problem: Some of the other functions I'm using perform a `Write-Output` operation. So my function returns the return-value PLUS a mix of text "injected" via the `Write-Output` cmdlets.

Comment: The stream moves ever forward. You can't clear it because what's written is written. You can clear the *screen*, but that's not the same thing, obviously. What you *can* do is take control of the stream -- `Write-Output` sends its output to the next command in the pipeline, so if you make sure that next command is there and discards the input (`Bad-Function | Out-Null`) it will never reach your caller.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Ok. Thx. Piping to `Out-Null` is a pattern I'm already using. Anyhow, pls. post your comment as the answer, so that I can close the question. Thx

Comment: Chained functions handeling the pipeline are processing the data in the pipeline concurrently. Once a function places something on the pipeline, it can't be removed anymore from within that function simply because the caller might have already processed and consumed it. Saying that, only the caller might pruge the data as suggested by Jeroen with something like `| Out-Null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Jeroen Mostert didn't post his comment as the answer I'll do it:

> The stream moves ever forward. You can't clear it because what's written is written. You can clear the screen, but that's not the same thing, obviously. What you can do is take control of the stream -- Write-Output sends its output to the next command in the pipeline, so if you make sure that next command is there and discards the input (Bad-Function | Out-Null) it will never reach your caller.